# Why does the ClientAppId column in the OfficeActivity table have guids that don't relate back to Enterprise Applications / App Registrations?

Tags: azure-sentinel

I am in Microsoft Azure Sentinel running a query against that OfficeActivity table. Guids are showing up in the ClientAppId column. I want to use these IDs to lookup details of the client application, however I cannot find a corresponding application in either the App Registration table nor the Enterprise Applications table.

Where else could these ClientAppIds be found?

Query:

```
OfficeActivity
| where ClientAppId != ""
```

Comment: Could you include the query that you are using by editing your question?

Comment: You can find all service principals in your Enterprise Applications tab. Check whether you applied any filters and make sure to select `All applications` field like this https://i.imgur.com/yZGizIg.png. Note that, you can search only with App name or **Object ID** in Enterprise applications. It will show "No results"  if you search with Client App ID.

Comment: @Dave did it solved your problem?

Comment: @Sridevi, Is there a place where I can search on ClientAppId? I image in this identifier must tie back to something. As far as I can tell, the OfficeActivity table does not have a column for "App Name" or "Object ID".

Comment: @NaveenSharma It did not. See my previous comment.